# problem to me vs problem for me?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

This sentence is struck in my head for almost 2 days now.

Should someone say "Speaking in English is not a problem to me" or "Speaking in English is not a problem for me"?

Comment: See also [important to me or important for me](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14484/important-to-me-or-important-for-me) see also [for me and to me](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/for-me-to-me-which-is-correct-or-better-in-these-examples)

Answer (score 2):

'For' is correct for 'I do not find it difficult to speak English'. 'To' would imply that you would have no difficulty understanding others speaking English.

'For' says that you do not create a problem, 'to' says that you would not have a problem with something that is already happening.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MaksI4cNQE

I'm sure this video will help.

'for' must precede a noun/pronoun in such a case. If you use 'to', it gives an impression of a problem being directed towards you and you certainly aren't trying to talk about direction here.

Hope that helped!