# No-brainer to me or no-brainer for me

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

When should we be using "to me", and for what occasions are "for me" better?

Take for instance the following sentence:

"It's a no-brainer to/for me that schools should be subsidized by the government."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expressing an option and I think “to me” would be more idiomatic here.

> It’s a no-brainer **to me** that schools should be subsidized by the government.

You could also make a point differently.

> **I find it obvious that** schools should be subsidized by the government.
>
> **It’s obvious to me that** schools should be subsidized by the government.

However, I am not sure if “for me” can be equally suitable here. I found [a related answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20020/53961) that may make it more clear.