# is 'the same to <somebody>' better than 'the same for <somebody>'

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which sentence is better? are they same?

> - All people are **the same to** them
> - All people are **the same for** them

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the adjective 'same' ALWAYS have the definite article 'the'?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/does-the-adjective-same-always-have-the-definite-article-the)

Comment: How is it duplicate? This question is about *"...same FOR.."* Vs. *"...same TO.."* and mine one was whether 'same' takes 'the' in all cases.

Comment: It asks about the nuance of *to* and *for* in this context. Nice question, worth keeping here +1

Comment: Both are valid, and mean much the same, but idiomatically,  ***to*** is far more common. Google Books [*"It's all the same **to** me"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It%27s+all+the+same+to+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) has a claimed 238,000 instances, whereas [*"It's all the same **for** me"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It%27s+all+the+same+for+me%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) has just 572. Arguably, ***to*** emphasises the *perception* of being the same, where ***for*** emphasises the *actual effect/influence*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of "to": can "to" here be replaced by "for"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/usage-of-to-can-to-here-be-replaced-by-for)

Comment: Alicja Z and StoneyB gave you good answers! @amanda

Comment: And this one: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20010/for-me-to-me-which-is-correct-or-better-in-these-examples?lq=1  @amanda

Comment: @amanda I proposed to close the answer not solely because of ['the same'](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/20432) problem, which was one of the problems that should be addressed in this question before the OP (amanda) edited it after my voted to close as a possible duplicate. But I was interrupted by something else, and soon forgot to add more useful information as I planned. For that, my apologies to the OP. However, there are a few more problems in the OP's sentences that need to be addressed because they make it difficult to answer this question.

Comment: To answer this quesion, which is, as @MaulikV pointed out, about 'the nuance of *to* and *for*, I think we'll need know who are these *them*, all people are the same to them or for them "in what way". Without these two facts, it's difficult to answer this question appropriately. Fortunately, FumbleFingers already gave a good explanation for the difference between *the same to* and *the same for* in general contexts, and Zhanlong Zheng already posted links to two related questions.

Comment: If I had to come up with something that makes sense to me, it might be something weird like this. -- I will use Venusians for the case of *All people are the same to them*. They came to Earth and thought to themselves, "I can't tell which one of them is which. All people look the same to me." -- As for the other case, *All people are the same for them,* I will use Martians. They came to Earth and thought to themselves, "All people are the same for me. All of them are equally good for me to eat. Yummy!"

Answer (score 1):

Take a clear example:

> Republican or Democrat - they both mean the same to John.

That usage is suggestive of an opinion or position held by John. Essentially (as suggested in an earlier comment by @magistermurphy) a subjective one.

> Republican or Democrat - they both mean the same for John.

Suggests that, whoever wins, the outcomes will be the same for John. Here the opinion is more objective or, at least, it is being offered as such by a third person

Answer (score 0):

Which is better will depend on context. The distinction is very subtle and almost entirely idiomatic.

I can't find any official information on this, so I can only give the idiomatic impression of a professional writer.

In my writing I would use "all the same to me" to describe the speakers reactions. The "me" is reacting to something, and the reaction is "it's all the same."

I would use "it's all the same for me" to describe the speakers assessment. The "me" is assessing the impact of something on them and their assessment is "It's all the same"

Comment: I also know of no official rules, but to my ears, "All people are the same to them," sounds like it emphasizes their subjective, erroneous impression that all people are the same, while "All people are the same for them," points of a less subjective impression, as in "All people are the same for them: unable to help." Do you agree?

Answer (score -1):

According to Cambridge Dictionaries Online **same to you** is an idiom and is used as [un answer to someone who has greeted or insulted you in order to wish the same thing to them](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/same-to-you).

Ex:

> Happy Christmas! - The same to you!
>
> Get lost! - Same to you!

As for the **same for you** it means roughly the same thing, but as Fumble Fingers points out in his comment, accentuates the actual effect/influence.

Comment: I think the idiom "[the] same to you" is generally used as an independent sentence.  The OP's examples don't contain this idiom.  I suppose this might be why someone downvoted.

Comment: @snailplane, thank you, for clarifying. I was puzzled indeed and didn’t really know the downvote’s reason